# How to declare an object of generic abstract class without specifying template type

Tags: c++, templates, abstract

I'm having some trouble learning generics in C++.

What I'm trying to achieve is having an abstract generic class

```
template <typename T>
class MediaEditor {
    public: virtual ~MediaEditor() = default;
}
```

Then 2 classes that extend it

```
class ImageEditor: public MediaEditor<TypeA> {}

class VideoEditor: public MediaEditor<TypeB> {}
```

Then in my main(), I want to declare a pointer of type MediaEditor like so :

```
MediaEditor* editor;
```

Since it is an abstract class, I was thinking that specifying the type was not needed, but gcc proved me wrong by telling me I have to specify type arguments.

So he expects me to declare it like this:

```
MediaEditor<SomeType>* editor;
```

But the whole point of what I'm trying to do is not having to specify those arguments and later use for example :

```
editor = new ImageEditor();
```

Do you guys have any idea how I could do instead ?

Comment: There is no common type `MediaEditor` which can be used for a pointer `MediaEditor*`. If you want to achieve this, you had to derive the template class from another base class, and that could be used for a pointer. Please, note: the template instances of `MediaEditor` are "co-classes" with no common ancestor.

Comment: Also note that `MediaEditor<TypeA>` and `MediaEditor<TypeB>` are different types.

Comment: For me it seems, there is a gap in your understanding of templates. Imagine a template like a plan to build a function/struct/class definition. For every template instance (e.g. `MediaEditor<TypeA>`), the compiler follows the plan and builds a new function/struct/class. Hence (as already said above), the resulting classes (i.e. template instances) are unrelated to each other (although similar as built by the same plan).

Comment: Oh ok I see your point, so I'll try with a base class on top of all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible directly, because those two

```
class ImageEditor: public MediaEditor<TypeA> {}

class VideoEditor: public MediaEditor<TypeB> {}
```

are completely unrelated types. Also `MediaEditor<TypeA>` and `MediaEditor<TypeB>` are two completely different types. Being instantiations of the same template does not impose any relation on the types (other than being instantiations of the same template).

If you want polymorphism, the solution is the same as it would be without templates: Use a common base class:

```
class MediaEditorBase {};

template <typename T>
class MediaEditor : MediaEditorBase {}
```

Now you can do

```
MediaEditorBase* x = new MediaEditor<int>();
```

PS: "generics in C++", strictly speaking C++ has no "generics". They are called templates and should not be confused with eg Java generics. Those are two rather different concepts.